# Trying to run .ahk files in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

this is my first time here so if I break some unwritten rules please don't shoot me
I've been trying build an app for editing, reading and opening .ahk files. The last one gives me problems.
this code kind of does what I want except it fires the command immediately after opening the app.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import threading

root = Tk()
def openfile():
    os.system( r'\Users\merijn\PycharmProjects\infoprojectP3\venv\Scripts\ahkScript1.ahk')
def func():
    print("hello")
btn1 = Button(text='programma', command=threading.Thread(target=openfile).start())
btn2 = Button(text='ander ding', command=func)
btn1.pack()
btn2.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you try to isolate the offending bit and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also the labels.py file is missing. One potential problem is that in `buttons.py` you are assigning to the name `list` which is a built-in function, this is not a good iddea. I don't have AHK installed so I cant test that particular bit...

Comment: @figbeam OP doesn't use the `list` built-in function so that can't be the problem.

Comment: I have no idea what `.ahk` files are but are they runnable from cmd without specifying a program to open them? (Basically would just typing `ahkScript3.ahk` in cmd work)

Comment: @TheLizzard just typing ahkScript3.ahk gives an error, but it runs fine if you specify the file path (\Users\merijn\PycharmProjects\infoprojectP3\venv\Scripts\ahkScript3.ahk)

Comment: @figbeam is this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line (it just assigns the result of `threading.Thread(...)` to `command` option):

```py
Button(text="run program1", command=threading.Thread(target=lambda: os.system(r'\Users\merijn\PycharmProjects\infoprojectP3\venv\Scripts\ahkScript1.ahk').start()))
```

to

```py
Button(text="run program1", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=lambda: os.system(r'\Users\merijn\PycharmProjects\infoprojectP3\venv\Scripts\ahkScript1.ahk')).start())
```

or

```py
Button(text="run program1", command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=[r'\Users\merijn\PycharmProjects\infoprojectP3\venv\Scripts\ahkScript1.ahk']).start())
```

Same for buttons of `run program2` and `run program3`.

---

**Update**: based on your updated code, you need to change the following line:

```py
btn1 = Button(text='programma', command=threading.Thread(target=openfile).start())
```

to

```
btn1 = Button(text='programma', command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=openfile).start())
```

Comment: Care to give a short explanation so that OP doesn't make the same mistake again?

Comment: @TheLizzard I have already explained at the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Didn't see it. Sorry